# Pivot in Oracle 10g and 11g r2

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table that I need to pivot. I am using oracle 11g R2 on my system and the server machine has oracle 10g running on it.

My table contains data:
Origin Table: ppl

```
ename | edate
emp1 | 01-10-17
emp1 | 01-10-17
emp1 | 01-10-17
emp1 | 02-10-17
emp2 | 01-10-17
emp3 | 01-10-17
emp3 | 01-10-17
emp3 | 02-10-17
emp3 | 02-10-17
```

Normally in pivot, output should be:
output table 1:

```
ename | 01-10-17 | 02-10-17
emp1  |      3   |      1
emp2  |      1   |      0
emp3  |      2   |      2
```

But here there is a condition that for each day count has to be >1. So desired output will be:
output table 2:

```
ename | 01-10-17 | 02-10-17
emp3  |      2   |      2
```

I used pivot in 11g to get required output and the output is partially correct.

```
select * from
(
  SELECT  ename, edate
  FROM ppl
)
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(edate)
  FOR edate in('01-oct-2017', '02-oct-2017')
)
order by ename;
```

The above query returns only the pivot in output table 1.
**My question 1 is where can I put filter in pivot query?**

On trying to get the same output in 10g, I found out that pivot command is not supported there.
So here is my query for 10g:

```
select ename,
  count(case when edate ='01-10-2017' then ename end) "01-OCT-2017",
  count(case when edate ='02-10-2017' then ename end) "02-OCT-2017"
from ppl
group by ename
having count(case when edate ='01-10-2017' then ename end) >1
and count(case when edate ='02-10-2017' then ename end) >1
order by ename;
```

This gives the exact output 2 table as desired.
**My question 2 is that the dates can range to 30 days even. As I can understand, for that case I need to write "count(case when edate ='01-10-2017' then ename end) "01-OCT-2017"" and "count(case when edate ='01-10-2017' then ename end) >1" 30 times.
Will not such a big query will hamper the time of output? Or is there any feasible way to do this better?**

Thank you for help..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. The where clause may be included prior to the pivot:

```
select * from
(
  SELECT  ename, edate
  FROM ppl

  WHERE .......
)
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(edate)
  FOR edate in('01-oct-2017', '02-oct-2017')
)
order by ename;
```

Q2. Yes you can have many case expressions, it will not be a big performance hit.

*Or is there any feasible way to do this better?* You could implement it through "dynamic SQL" instead, but the query structure will remain the same. Dynamic sql just builds the query SQL for you.

Comment: The green is for Q2.